# close colorbox on link click within the colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a colorbox window which calls a small html page (iframe).  The page called contains a link to another page on the main site (i.e. from which the colorbox was triggered.)

At the moment, clicking the link loads the new page into the colorbox. I don't want that. How do I make clicking the link close the colorbox and open the new page in the regular browser window?

Comment: If that really is a link. Did you try to add target="_blank" to the anchor?

Comment: Hi jPO..... no I didn't.  I thought adding target = "blank" would just open yet another window, and that's not desired, either!  But maybe my thought is wrong?...I'll give it a go.